# project structure from subversion to git

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

I have a typical trunk/tags subversion repository structure and now moving to git was wondering what the typical/conventional/known structure is, the same as in subversion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tags and branches in git are not reflected as part of the file tree in the
repository. The tree stored in the repository would most closely correspond to
what is stored in the `trunk` directory of a typical svn repository.

Most conversion tools would translate the svn trunk into a git branch named
`master`, which is the traditional name for the main branch in git. But, unlike
in the traditional svn layout, there is nothing special (to git) about the
master branch.

Tags in git are normally stored in yet a different way. They would be
manipulated using the `git tag` command. They are similar to branches, but git
makes it difficult to update a tag after it has been created. Because there is
nothing preventing modification of tags in a standard svn repository, tools for
converting that to git will often convert svn tags into git branches with names
indicating that they're from tags rather than creating git tags; but git tags
can be created at a later point based on those branches.